# addEventDelegate Not fired After Drop in Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, sapui5, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to implement drag and drop funcitonality between two lists.

I'm able to drag and drop the list item from One list to another. However, after the drop , the second list ( which receives the element) is no more droppable.

I checked the DOM and found that list does not has the droppable class "ui-droppable". This class was added to the list using the jquery plugin droppable by extending OnAfterRendering.

I also found out, that once the List re-renders itself after receiving the element, it does not call the Delegated Events.

SO basially, how do I add the funcationality back to my draggable list since It does not call delegated events?

Code:

XML Lists:

```
     <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
        <items>
            <List 
                headerText='Players'
                id='players' 
                items='{/players}'>
                <layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                </layoutData>
                <items>
                    <ObjectListItem
                        title="{name}" >
                        <attributes>
                            <ObjectAttribute
                            title='Role'
                            text="{role}" />
                            <ObjectAttribute
                            title='Rating'
                            text="{rating}" />
                        </attributes>
                    </ObjectListItem>
                </items>
                </List>

                <List 
                headerText='Playing XI'
                id='playing' 
                items='{playing>/playing}'>
                <layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                </layoutData>
                <items>
                    <StandardListItem
                        title="{playing>name}" />
                </items>
                </List>
        </items>
    </HBox>
```

Controller:

```
oDragList.addEventDelegate({
            "onAfterRendering": function(oEvent) {
                $("#" + idDragList + "-listUl li").sortable({
                      revert: true
                });
                $("#" + idDragList + "-listUl li").draggable({
                     helper: "clone"
                });
            }
        });

        oDragList.addEventDelegate({
            "onAfterRendering": function(oEvent) {
                $("#" + oDropListId + "-listUl li").sortable({
                      revert: true
                });

                $("#" + oDropListId).droppable({
                    drop: function(evt, ui) {
//                      debugger;
                        var oControl = ui.draggable.control()[0];
//                      debugger;
                        var oContext = oControl.getBindingContext().getObject();
                        var srcControl = evt.srcControl,
                            oPlayingModel = srcControl.getModel("playing");

                        oPlayingModel.getProperty("/playing").push(oContext);
                        oPlayingModel.refresh();
                    }
                });



            }
        });
```

Dummy Data:

```
var data = [
            {
                name:"Sachin Tendulkar",
                role:"Batsman",
                rating:"100"
            },

            {
                name:"Saurav Ganguly",
                role:"Batsman",
                rating:"78"
            }
];
```

DOM before Drag:
[image]

DOM After Drag:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your controller. I tried with below code. It is emitting the event when I drop on the second list.

```
onInit : function() {
    var dragList = this.getView().byId("players");
    dragList.addEventDelegate({
        "onAfterRendering": function(oEvent) {
            $("#" + dragList.getId() + "-listUl li").sortable({
                 revert: true
            });
            $("#" + dragList.getId() + "-listUl li").draggable({
                helper: "clone"
            });
         }
    });

    var dropList = this.getView().byId("playing");
    dropList.addEventDelegate({
        "onAfterRendering": function(oEvent) {
            $("#" + dropList.getId() + "-listUl li").sortable({
                revert: true
            });
            $("#" + dropList.getId()).droppable({
                drop: function(evt, ui) {
                    //You will get your event here. You can do your stuff
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yes it firing drop event when you drop to second list but only once. Drop a list item and then try again. I wonder whats in my drop code which is causing event to not be fired again. Unable to find it.

Comment: It is working fine for the multiple times also. I am able drag and drop more than once.

Comment: You are adding the second **addEventDelegate**  to **oDragList**. You should add it on **oDropList**.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj Is it because of that or is there anything causing this problem.

Comment: Only problem was what you highlight. I added addEventDelegate to oDragList second time as well ( should've added to oDragList. That was wrong. Please write that in you answer. :)